# Unable to restore from Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've successfully created a snapshot of database SCPT_Pandora named SCPT_Pandora_snap. When I try to restore SCPT_Pandora from this snapshot, I get an error ("'DATABASE_SHAPSHOT' is not a recognized Device Type option"). I've tried this on two servers (2005 & 2008 Enterprise editions) and received the same error on both.  Here's the code:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  name
        FROM    sys.databases
        WHERE   name = N'SCPT_Pandora_snap' ) 
DROP DATABASE SCPT_Pandora_snap
GO

CREATE DATABASE SCPT_Pandora_snap ON

(

    NAME = SCPT_Pandora,

    FILENAME = 'D:\SQL2008_data\SCPT_Pandora_snap.ss'

) AS SNAPSHOT OF SCPT_Pandora

GO

USE Master
GO

RESTORE DATABASE SCPT_Pandora FROM DATABASE_SHAPSHOT = 'SCPT_Pandora_snap';
GO
```

Thanks!

Comment: All the examples on MSDN do `USE master;` before the `restore`.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: I was already running this against the master db; i've updated the code sample to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo, you're restoring from a sHapshot:

```
RESTORE DATABASE SCPT_Pandora FROM DATABASE_SHAPSHOT = 'SCPT_Pandora_snap';
                                            ^^^
```